# alternating series $\sum(-1)^na_n$ is divergent, then, is $\sum A_k$ divergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

An alternating series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n$ is divergent , $a_n\geq0$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Could we conclude that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ is divergent, too ? where

$$A_k=(-1)^{n_{k-1}+1}a_{n_{k-1}+1}+(-1)^{n_{k-1}+2}a_{n_{k-1}+2}+\dotsb+ (-1)^{n_k}a_{n_k}$$

and, $1\leq n_1\lt n_2\lt\dotsb\to\infty$

---

I think the answer is "NO". But, How to construct a counterexample? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "divergent" you mean precisely "not convergent" (as opposed to "diverges to $+\infty$" or something), then the answer is indeed no.

Set $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=0$. For each $m\ge2$, define $a_{2^m+1}$ through $a_{2^{m+1}}$ as follows:
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
2^{-m}, &\text{if } 2^m < n \le 3\cdot 2^{m-1} \text{ and $n$ is odd}, \\
0, &\text{if } n \le 3\cdot 2^{m-1} \text{ and $n$ is even}, \\
0, &\text{if } 3\cdot 2^{m-1} < n \le 2^{m+1} \text{ and $n$ is odd}, \\
2^{-m}, &\text{if } 3\cdot 2^{m-1} < n \le 2^{m+1} \text{ and $n$ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$
So the sequence begins
\begin{multline*}
\{a_n\} = \{0,0,0,0,\tfrac14,0,0,\tfrac14,\tfrac18,0,\tfrac18,0,0,\tfrac18,0,\tfrac18, \\
\tfrac1{16},0,\tfrac1{16},0,\tfrac1{16},0,\tfrac1{16},0,0,\tfrac1{16},0,\tfrac1{16},0,\tfrac1{16},0,\tfrac1{16},\dots\}.
\end{multline*}
Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2^m} (-1)^n a_n = 0 \quad\text{but}\quad \sum_{n=1}^{3\cdot 2^{m-1}} (-1)^n a_n = \frac14
$$
for all $m\ge2$, so the original series diverges; yet if $n_k = 2^k$, then each $A_k$ equals $0$, so the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ converges.